# Extracting mp4 video from YouTube URL and playing that video on a Player in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, youtube, windows-phone-8

I want to Extract mp4 format video from YouTube url and play that mp4 video on sort of a player embedded in windows phone 8 app ( player should be windows phone 8 compatible )

Comment: _Did you tried anything so far?_ Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I have retrieved all MetaData from Youtube url using XML parsing ,, and i want to extract mp4 stream from that url but not successfull :(